# Can't remove entities iterating over collection, but I can remove getting them directly from repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My `News` entity is connected with `Document` entity through joiner `NewsDocument` entity with some extra fields: News -> NewsDocument <- Document

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="news_document")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"news", "document"}
 * )
 */
class NewsDocument
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Document", inversedBy="news")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $document;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\News", inversedBy="documents")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $news;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $position;
```

My `News` entity

```php
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\NewsDocument", mappedBy="news", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $documents;
    
    public function getNewsDocuments()
    {
        return $this->documents;
    }
```

When I tried to remove each `NewsEntity` iterating over `documents` field of my `News` entity, the `NewsEntity` wasn't removed from DB.

```php
$news = $this->entityManager->getRepository(News::class)->find(26);
foreach($news->getNewsDocuments() as $newsDocument) {
    $this->entityManager->remove($newsDocument);
}
$this->entityManager->remove($news);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

`News` was deleted but `NewsDocument` not.

However the following code is able to remove both entities.

```php
$news = $this->entityManager->getRepository(News::class)->find(26);
$newsDocument = $this->entityManager->getRepository(NewsDocument::class)->find(1);
$this->entityManager->remove($newsDocument);
$this->entityManager->remove($news);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

I don't understand why first code isn't able to remove `NewsDocument` from DB.

I dumped `$newsDocument` variable in both cases and looked similar to each others.

Comment: no error message, nothing? however, you could think about using the cascade on the one-to-many sides.

Comment: I tried the cascade approach, but I had got the same problem. This is why I tried do it manually. There are no errors, no DB transactions involved etc. I ended up with following solution `$newsDocuments = $this->entityManager->getRepository(NewsDocument::class)->findBy(['news' => $news->getId()]);

        foreach ($newsDocuments as $newsDocument) {
            $this->entityManager->remove($newsDocument);
        }`
but I have no clue why this relation doesn't work nativly.

Answer (score 0):

I probably found a problem. My `News` entity uses `SoftDeletable` extension for Doctrine, but the joiner entity doesn't. I guess that extension tries to set a `deleted_at` flag to the relation, instead of deleting it permanently. This is why if I get joiner entity directly from repository works correctly.